# Not use Google Analytics could penalize page rank in Google Search?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search, yandex

I am using Yandex Metrika as tool for analytics. However I am concerned about the impacts in terms of SEO. For example. How Google knows how much time the users stay in this website? I mean, things like bounce rate, direct traffic, these type of things will be hidden to Google since I am not using Google analytics?

Or Yandex Metrika share these type of data with Google? I am afraid that I am losing some good data to improve my page ranking in Google Search. Anyone could clarify if my concerns have some logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google collects users behavioral data independently of websites having Google Analytics installed.

Types of user behavior data used by Google include click-through rate (CTR), navigational paths, time, duration, and frequency.

The way they do this is by tracking users behavior on each set of organic search results in the same way they do with paid ads, in simple words, they basically store in a database data associated with the use of all the links appearing in SERPs. Search engines also weigh the probability of a link being clicked in relation to its position and how this influences further user’s behavior on those websites a user visits, becoming arguably an essential part of how the algorithm works.

Be conscious with this idea, Google as a service provider will track users and their relationship with your website, not websites. Of course, they will crawl your website to classify the information it is providing in response to their users queries, but they will essentially track and try to determine their users level of satisfaction.

Picture this, an user query a search engine and clicks one of the links Google is providing, either the same user comes back to the same SERP and clicks another link, refine the initial query or never comes back. All these possible actions by the user are expected and being tracked to measure how well the result set is providing the right information in response to the user search intent. Google will make sure they are providing the right answer to their users, and reassess if necessary to provide a more tailored result set.

Google Analytics is a tool to provide information to you, it is part of an ecosystem Google have created to serve webmasters and of course provide some other benefits to them, but they will not rely on everyone to install Google Analytics to have the necessary information to improve their services.

Check out this video where Google clarifies that [they do not use Google Analytics Data For Rankings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgBw9tbAQhU)

Comment: It is important for the OP and others to understand that Google uses AI (artificial intelligence) against all search queries and SERPs for analysis. For this to happen, data must be complete. Since most web sites do not have GA installed, it cannot be a part of the process. GA is wholely separate from the search engine simply because of the noise in the data from GA would distort the analysis across the board. Cheers!!

Comment: CTR, bounce rate or dwell time or most of those statistics are not relevant for search. Some examples: If your website points directly to an answer the user was looking for, then the dwell or visit time is very short and bounce rate is high. If a similar website has bad navigation and a bad structure, the same user for the same question will search longer on this website for the answer and bounce rate is low.

But a website with good navigation, structure, related articles and so on, then its good that a user takes more time... but bounce rate is low then...

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct link between not having Google Analytics as your tool and your ranking in Google. Google will crawl your site like usual. However, I do recommend to set up your website in Google Webmasters Tools as you can control important settings there, in example preferred version of site (www/non-www), you can adjust international targeting, find crawl errors and other suggestions. There are many benefits to using Webmasters Tools and the settings within may have impact on the rankings.

In short, Google Analytics doesn't impact rankings in my understanding, however Google Webmasters Tools can have a positive effect after minor configuration.